# How can I check the validity of a column elements in MySQL that were derived from another column of the same table?

Tags: mysql, database, data-science, data-analysis

For example, if I have a Project_ID = 123456 in one column and Project_Name = R123456. I want to check if Project_Name was correctly input with prefix R in every elements. What query can I use?

Comment: *I have a Project_ID = 123456 in one column and Project_Name = R123456* Overdefined data is bad practice. Store Project_ID only, generate Project_Name in the query with according expression or use generated column.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Project_ID,
       case when Project_Name = concat('R', Project_ID) 
            then 'ok' 
            else 'fail'
       end as result
from your_table
```

or to get only the ones that are not correct:

```
select Project_ID
from your_table
where Project_Name <> concat('R', Project_ID)
```